# How to Read 1st line of a file with BufferedReader?

Tags: java, android, file-io, io

I was experimenting with BufferedReader to read 1st line file to a string. How do I do this? Also how can I read an entire file to a string? How to read a particular line like `readline(int line)` without iterating through the previous lines?

```
File namefile = new File(root, ".name");
FileReader namereader = new FileReader(namefile);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(namereader);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175161/how-to-get-file-read-line-by-line see if it can be of help it is something similar you wish to achieve

Comment: If (from your comments to answers) you want to know how access arbitrary lines in a file without reading the whole file up to that point (random access) you should clarify the wording of your question.

Comment: @dev Sorry, I speak English but it's a bit difficult for me to word this properly as I don't have much of a programming background. Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) to get the first line.

Note that the next call to `readLine()` will get you the 2nd line, and the next the 3rd line....

**EDIT:**

If you want to specify a specific line, as your comment suggest - you might want to use Apache Commons FileUtils, and use: [`FileUtils.readLines()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29). It will get you a [`List<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true) which you can handle like any list, including getting a specific line. Note that it has more overhead because it reads the entire file, and populates a `List<String>` with its lines.

Comment: Is it possible to specify a particular line?

Comment: @BinoyBabu: Look at my edit, if you want a specific line - you might want to use apache commons - `FileUtils`

Comment: @Binoy you should edit your question to include that criteria if that is what your looking for.

Comment: @amit: can you give me example to write specific line on file? - let say that i have file.txt with three lines. line number1. a, number2. b, number3. c. then i want to rewrite line number 3 to d. how to do that? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Um, what's wrong with [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)?

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

(I don't see any sign of a `readFile()` method though - what documentation were you looking at?)

Personally I prefer to use `FileInputStream` wrapped in `InputStreamReader` instead of `FileReader` by the way, as otherwise it will always use the platform default encoding - are you sure what's what you want?

Comment: It reads the file as a whole right? I can't specify a line like BufferedReader.readLine(1);

Comment: @BinoyBabu: No, it reads a line, as documented. Look at the name of the method **readLine**, not **readFile**.

Comment: Since the reader is buffered, BufferedReader#readLine will most probably read more than the first line from the underlying source, even if it's only invoked once. From a performance point of view, this is probably irrelevant in most cases, but there are situations where the functionality difference is relevant.

Comment: @jarnbjo: Yes, quite possibly - but that's not the same thing as reading the whole *file* which is what the OP seems to have been concerned about.

Answer (score 3):

```
final File namefile = new File(root, ".name");
final FileReader namereader = new FileReader(namefile);
final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(namereader);
in.readLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the BufferedReader to read the File there should be a Method called

```
readLine()
```

wich reads exactly one Line.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Answer (score 0):

See the readline() method of the BufferedReader.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29