# Line by line textfile reading in android

Tags: android, text-files, line-by-line

The problem may be familiar and may even be tagged as a duplicate. I have tried reading other problems similar to mine and tried to do it, might as say copied it (xD), but to no avail though.

I am new to Android Programming and I am trying to read a text file. I was able to read the whole text file, but what I want is to read the text file line by line. Then click the next button to display the next line. How I should do that?

This is what I have as of the moment. . .

```
public class QuestionActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    try {
        in = this.getAssets().open("hhquestion.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    try {
        line = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    text.setText(line);
    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);

} //onCreate

public void onClick(View v){
    try {
        line = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (line != null){
        text.setText(line);
    } else {
        //you may want to close the file now since there's nothing more to be done here.
    }
    } //onClick

} //main class
```

I have tried the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175161/how-to-get-file-read-line-by-line), as this was the nearest solution to my question, but when I run the project, the app is closing.
Thank you.

Logcat:

```
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907): Process: asp.ons.scads, PID: 1907
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{asp.ons.scads/asp.ons.scads.QuestionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at asp.ons.scads.QuestionActivity.onCreate(QuestionActivity.java:43)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-07 00:06:06.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Hi, do you have any log when your app is closing?

Comment: @CuongHuynh, logcat posted . . .

Comment: I see you got a NullPointerException at QuestionActivity.java line 43. I think you forgot init an Object before using it.

Comment: already fixed. i re-coded the whole activity, xD, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine..but to display line when you click next button u need to `setonClickListener()` for next Button.

```
    public class QuestionActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    static InputStream inputStream;
    static InputStreamReader inputreader;
    static BufferedReader bufferedreader;
    String data;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hellotxt);
        Button next=(Button) findViewById(R.id.next); // next button id for suppose..

        inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

        inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

        bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
             try 
             {
                 while (( line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) 
                 {
                  data+=line+"\n";
                 }
              } 
           catch (IOException e) {}

              textView.setText(data);
            }
          });

    } //onCreate

  } //main class
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to read the whole text file, but what I want is to read the text file line by line. Then click the next button to display the next line. How I should do that?

In your current loop, you have each line being saved to the `line` variable, which is then appended to `stringBuilder` with a newline.

Instead of appending it to `stringBuilder`, you could add `line` to some sort of array each iteration, and then access the next element each time the user clicks the next button.

Or, you could do something with the returned `stringBuilder` and the newlines you add to the end of each line, such as `split` (which essentially gives you the same as the above, but using your already written code). So at the end of `onCreate`, you would call `split` to get an array of strings split by the newline character:

```
String[] lines = data.toString().split("\\n");
```

and then each time the user clicks the button, you could increment a counter and get the line for the element at counter, or you could get a little more complex and remove the element from the array as you read it (although you may not want an array in that case).

Comment: I had written this based on the code you originally posted, so it doesn't really apply the same now.